# Using window.open within a modalDialog - address bar always visible?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, window.open

(This problem has been observed in IE9)

I am experiencing some problems relating to the display of an address bar when opening a new window from within a modalDialog.

The following sample page illustrates this.

test.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function windowOpen()
            {
                var sOptions = "width=300,height=300,location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0";
                window.open("test.html", "", sOptions);
            }

            function modal()
            {
                var sOptions = "dialogHeight:300px;dialogWidth:300px;";
                window.showModalDialog("test.html", "", sOptions);
            }
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="modal()">window.showModalDialog</a><br /><br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="windowOpen()">window.open</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Clicking on the 'window.open' link on the page works as expected and the address bar is hidden. If you click the link again in the resulting new window, it still performs as expected.

If however, you open the page in a modalDialog at any point (using the window.showModalDialog link) and then click on 'window.open' the address bar is visible.

Is there any way of avoiding this behaviour?

Any help would be appreciated.